# How to show data in datagridview without using database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to show data in datagridview without using Database. In my UI there are 3 fields in which I inserted values and want to show them in data grid view when I execute the program it is not giving any error nor showing any values in datagridview.

[image: Picture]

```
   private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtBox1.Text;
        dr[1] = txtBox2.Text;
        dr[2] = txtBox3.Text;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Email");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("ConatctNumber");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dt.Rows.Add(dc1);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {    
         dt.Columns.Add ("Name");
         dt.Columns.Add ("Email");
         dt.Columns.Add ("ConatctNumber");        
        // dt.Rows.Add(dc1); dc1 is a column not a row   >>>
        // DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();  not necessary
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
       }
     private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = txtBox1.Text;
            dr[1] = txtBox2.Text;
            dr[2] = txtBox3.Text;
             dt.rows.add(dr);   //You forgot to add new row in your datatable
          //  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; is already definedin loadForm
        }
```

Comment: `dt` is inaccessible due to its scope.

Comment: Glad to hear that and hapy to help

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you need to do is **add** the new row to the `DataTable`:

```
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = txtBox1.Text;
    dr[1] = txtBox2.Text;
    dr[2] = txtBox3.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);             // <<< ====
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Note that there is no constructor for `DataRow` but the `DataTable.NewRow()` call only uses the table layout as a **template** for the columns in the new row; it doesn't actually add it to the table.

Comment: `dt` is inaccessible because of scope of variable.

Comment: Nonsense. It has to be a class level variable or else the OP code would not compile. (It could to be retracked vie DataSource etc, but this makes not much  sense..)

Comment: Take a look at code provided by OP. Where a `dt` variable is declared?

Comment: Not to be seen. Which means __nothing__ . It is used though( twice)  in the button click.  and it is __not__ declared locally. So assuming it is declared at class level is the logical conclusion.. @Maciej Sorry __if__ I misread your original solution. It does look ok in its last version.

Comment: I do not see `dt` declaration right now. I was sure that declaration of `dt` variable has been provided in `Load` method. Seems, i've been wrong.